# How to repurpose an old self inflating sleeping pad?

Tags: gear, repairs, sleeping-pads

I have some damaged-beyond-repair self inflating sleeping pads. 
On one the hard gel housing the valve has completely disintegrated so it cannot be inflated at all.

Two others have dozens of tiny holes, courtesy of the cats’ claws. While I started patching the holes with blobs of silicone gel, I gave up as there seemed to be just too many. They can be fully inflated but slowly deflate after a couple of hours. I’ve used the ¾ size one as a “lunch pad” on day hikes but it seems a bit overkill for such brief usage.

How have you successfully repurposed your old self inflating sleeping mats?

Comment: Sometimes things have to be thrown away.  You might use them as sleeping pads for your cats, but your cats, having ruined them, probably have no further interest in them.

Answer (score 8):

My only thought is to use them as patching material for the other self-inflating pads your kitties will puncture. Cutting them to-size for inside an animal crate or other surface you want to protect.

Answer (score 6):

If you ever have to get into a crawlspace under a house or car, pads like this can be invaluable in making it more comfortable; especially where you are lying on your back to do something.

Insulation/lagging for something temporarily needed - broken window, new pipe until you can get lagging sorted. Pads are perfect for that sort of thing.

You could also cut it up for filler in packaging if you are shipping something fragile.

Answer (score 3):

If you used them always putting up the same side most of the holes might be on the same face. You could try and glue two or all the three together. It wouldn't be very portable, but you could still get a thick pad that you could use as a cushion in your home.

Answer (score 0):

What if you make a poncho out of it. Water shouldnt be able to go through everything but the tiny hole that has been created. Hmmmmm